# how to change external HDD name/drive in ubuntu like in windows

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, drive

I have 3 external HDD for backup/media. They are all WD easystore drives so in ubuntu they all show up with the same name like easystore easystore1 easystore2. When I try to set one of the drives for all my downloads it will work until the next reboot. Sometimes one of the drives might mount/boot faster than the other and will be labeled as the other drive. For example easystore will become easystore1 so the path is no longer /media/usr/easystore instead it's /media/usr/easystore1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Disks utility can do it.

Comment: Is the problem that the mount point isn't consistent? Is there an entry in /etc/fstab for the partitions/drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different tools, depending on your knowledge or expectations. The technical operation to perform is to change the partition label of the partition on your external HDD.

For the GUI, there is **Disks** as already mentionned or **gparted**. Choose to change the partition label.

If you want to use the command line in a terminal, you need to know the filesystem of your partition, because the tool is different for each FS.

For NTFS (you need to properly unmount it in *Windows* if you **dual-boot**. In the *systray*, click the up-arrow and then the usb key, and then your hdd),

```
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdcx MYNEWLABEL
```

For ext4,

```
sudo tune2fs -L MYNEWLABEL /dev/sdcx
```

For XFS,

```
sudo xfs_admin -L MYNEWLABEL /dev/sdcx
```

For btrfs,

```
sudo btrfs filesystem label <mountpoint/device> MYNEWLABEL
```

Note: the label does not need to be all capitals.

You can use `lsblk` to find your partition device name

Comment: I used the disks gui and changed the name, but now in my file manager it just displays it as ' and not the name i gave it. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: never mind I figured it out. I had to change the filesystem name too. One of the drives I'm getting another very long error. This is it: Error setting lable: Command-line `ntfslabel "/dev/sda1" "8TB" exited with non-zero exit status 1: Volume is scheduled for check. Please boot into Windows TWICE, or use the 'force' option. NOTE: If you had not scheduled check and last time accessed this volume using ntfsmount and shutdown system properly, then init  scripts in your distribution are broken....

Comment: ...  Please report to your distribution developers (NOT to us!) that init scripts kill ntfsmount or mount.ntfs-fuse during shutdown instead of proper mount. (udisks-error-quark, 0) - I think I know what the problem is here, I probably just have to do shutdown -s from cmd in windows because i'm using dual boot and windows never does a shutdown completely